# How to rewrite url with apache htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website:

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1&start=36`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1&start=72`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=2`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1&start=36`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1&start=72`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&category=1&keyword=test`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&keyword=test&start=36`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&keyword=test&start=72`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&start=36`

`http://www.test.com/?city=beijing&start=72`

if i want to rewrite it as
`http://www.test.com/beiing/1/36`

can any one tell me the code for this to write in .htaccess file.?

Answer (score 0):

you need to systematize, in such cases, the order of parameters is important:

```
# ...
RewriteRule /([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ?city=$1&category=$2&start=$3
# ...
```